# Wrong result when converting a date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just a beginner. My original date is: Friday, September 16th 2016, 09:00

And I need to convert it to this format: Fri Sep 16 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

But my code shows wrong date: Tue Sep 06 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

Please see my code here:

```
var startdate = "Friday, September 16th 2016, 09:00";
var sdate = new Date(startdate.replace(/(\d)+(st|nd|th)/g, '$1'));
alert(new Date(sdate));
```

Can anybody help me with this issue? The example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/5hzwbbku/3/

By using momentjs I receive the strange results: https://jsfiddle.net/5hzwbbku/13/

Comment: Use moment.js for date calculations in JavaScript.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 moment.js couldn't pick up my initial format unfortunately. Justo don't understand why results not showing correctly

Comment: Timezones what's wrong. Using moment.js should simply things.

Comment: hi @evolutionxbox can you please show me an example? I am really a beginner and don't have a clue. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you do not provide a timezone, it will take your browser's one. So, actually, you just need to provide the timezone.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 the date I have got is only in this format: Friday, September 16th 2016, 09:00
so no difference what the timezone it in. can you show the example on my jsfiddle please?

Comment: `moment("Friday, September 16th 2016, 09:00 +0000", "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm ZZ")`

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I have tried your example here: https://jsfiddle.net/5hzwbbku/9/ but it didn't work. can you please help?

Comment: I think the problem is in your regexp. It should be `startdate.replace(/(.\d)+(st|nd|th)/g, '$1')`. Your current regexp is returning `"Friday, September 6 2016, 09:00"`.

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't just examine the result of your regex replace. Basic debugging! Come on!

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Ah yes, that famous "UTC minus 10 days" timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. `/(\d)+(st|nd|th)/g` matches the `16th` but the captured group only contains `6`. In order to return `16` your regex needs to be `/(\d+)(st|nd|th)/g`, like so:

```
var sdate = new Date(startdate.replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|th)/g, '$1'));
```

If you need the time to be in UTC, you'll have to append a timezone such as `+0`, `+0000`, or simply `Z` (for Zulu time).

```
var startdate = "Friday, September 16th 2016, 09:00";
startdate = startdate + ' +0000';
var sdate = new Date(startdate.replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|th)/g, '$1'));
alert(new Date(sdate));
```

On my system that returns `Fri Sep 16 2016 11:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)` which is 09:00 in UTC.

Other regexes that match correctly are `/(\d)(st|nd|th)/g` (note the complete absence of the `+`) and the one given by pastine in the comments `/(.\d)+(st|nd|th)/g`.

Comment: OP should have printed out the value. Tsk.